# jQuery - Close external link windows forcefully

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a main application, with in that i have many external links. This external links can open in same window but as different tabs, or as a separate window. When i logout from main application.I want this external tabs / windows to get close automatically. Is there any way to implements this ?

Comment: You can not touch them. Same Origin Policy

Comment: Can't we set window name while openning tabs, and later when we logout, access those tabs by name and close forcefuly. I am not sure want to confirm on this.

Comment: if you control the external domains, you could use some server-side based system that detects when the main app is closed, then on the satellite windows periodically check with the server to see if they need to be closed.

Comment: Are you sure these windows are external, meaning they are on a different origin?

Comment: Not completely different origin, they are part of main app, but will open them as seperate tab or window.

Comment: So, they're all from the same protocol, subdomain, domain, and port? In that case they aren't external and you can simply open and close them with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to just use a `<a href=""></a>` for your links.

```
var w=window.open('/somwherelse.html');
w.close();
```

`window.open` returns the window object of the new page that was opened ***if, and only if* that page is on the same website**.  For security reasons, you cannot open a window to a different website and the close it.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/24xbC/).

Comment: This worked, but if i have open link as new window. Its not working.

Comment: Also suppose if click link for 3 times, then 3 tabs will be opened. But it will close only the recently opened tab :(

Comment: Any suggestion how can i make this happen ? Let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: Here's a fixed [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/24xbC/4/) that works with lots of tabs.  It just stores all the different windows in an array and closes them all with a loop.